# "Starting Rasa server on http://localhost:5005" how do I change localhost to a particular VM's address and how to run the RASA model?

Tags: virtual-machine, chatbot, rasa

I deployed my Rasa Bot on a VM, and ran it using rasa run. But when the server up and running it shows as "Starting Rasa server on http://localhost:5005". But I want my bot to work on the VM's address so that I can use it for the webhooks. Without using ngrok. Which files should I customize and how do I run my model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to solve this with your VM configuration, not with Rasa config files. You probably need to bridge your VM and host networks.